# Will newer lenses work completely on a Canon 5D?

Tags: lens, canon

I have a Canon 5D and been using older lens on the camera. But I never bought a newer lens since I was afraid that the hardware (image stabilizer, focus, etc..)  on the newer lens won't work with the older software/hardware on the body. Has anyone tried it out? If so can you tell me your experience with the camera.

Answer (score 2):

All Canon EF (not EF-S) lenses will work with the camera. What kind of experience you are looking for? It is a fine camera. Current 5D series models have faster autofocus, less noise and higher resolution than the original 5D.

Comment: I was just wondering cause I don't want to spend more money into a newer camera when the old one is just fine. Since most of the image quality (from what I understand) comes from the lens.

Comment: The image quality comes from both. Whether camera or lens is a better investment for you depends on the style of photography, your typical print sizes and quality of your current lens. Perhaps you could rent the latest 5D and a lens of your choice, do your own comparison mixing your old and the new and get a feel for the new equipment. You will see what is making bigger difference on your own eyes, which is better than any internet advice or review...